# ExtJS Model with repeating structures

Tags: extjs

What patterns have been successful when mapping a model with a few repeating structures.
I have to model and create a grid view a record with has a few columns which are basically the same repeating structure.

```
Ext.define('Ep.mm.model.MyComparison', {
var derived = function(val,)
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        {name:'id',type:'string'},
        {name:'count',type:'number'},
        {name:'special',type:'number'},
        {name:'A_a',type:'number'},
        {name:'A_b',type:'number'}
        {name:'A_derived',renderer = function(val,meta,rec){return rec.get('A_b')-rec.get('A_a')}}
        {name:'B_a',type:'number'},
        {name:'B_b',type:'number'}
        {name:'B_derived',renderer = function(val,meta,rec){return rec.get('B_b')-rec.get('B_a')}}
        {name:'C_a',type:'number'},
        {name:'C_b',type:'number'}
        {name:'C_derived',renderer = function(val,meta,rec){return rec.get('C_b')-rec.get('C_a')}}
    ]
});
```

I am likely to end up with Server models/stores that differ only in the number of times this structure repeats (A) (A,B) (A,B,C,D). Is there a way to use a common model for each of A,B,C,D and just re-use the common model as the type. This is something akin to a 'nested' structure.

```
Ext.define('MyType',{
   extend :'Ext.data.Model',
   fields : [
      {name : 'a', type:'number'},
      {name : 'b', type:'number'},
      {  name : 'derived', 
         convert : function(value, record) {
            return record.get('a') - record.get('b');
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Then MyComparison would be defined as

```
Ext.define('Ep.mm.model.MyComparison',{
   extend : 'Ext'data.Model',
   fields : [
      {name:'A', type:'MyType'}
      {name:'B', type:'MyType'}
      {name:'C', type:'MyType'}
   ]
});
```

I know this isn't quite right, but this is sort of the functionality I am trying to create.
Perhaps using the 'hasOne' association type?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can extend your own model classes:

```
Ext.define('Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name']
});

Ext.define('Child', {
    extend: 'Base',
    fields: ['age']
});

var o = new Child({
    name: 'Foo',
    age: 100
});
console.log(rec.get('name'), rec.get('age'));
```

As a sidenote, models don't have renderers. You're probably looking for the convert function on the field, [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you want functionality of a field [type](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Types):

```
Ext.data.Types.A_DERIVED = {
    convert: function(v, data) {
        return rec.get('A_b')-rec.get('A_a');
    },
    type: 'number'
};
```

Then use it as a type of `A_derived` field:

```
Ext.define('Ep.mm.model.MyComparison', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name:'id',type:'string'},
        {name:'A_a',type:'number'},
        {name:'A_b',type:'number'},
        {name:'A_derived', type: 'Ext.data.Types.A_DERIVED'}
    ]
});
```

Afterthoughts:
- Maybe you would like to aggregate all `A_*` data into one field? See [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Types) for an example.
- There is a trouble when you want to use the same mechanism with `B_derived` because there is no way of supplying `B` into `convert` function. A dirty hack might be to set the [defaultValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-defaultValue) to `B` and to bind the field to null data. Then `v` would be read from `defaultValue`.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was thinking, combined with aggregating all A_* data into one field, all B_* data into another field. Since A_* data and B_* data have the same set of fields, I was hoping their is way to use another model as the field's type. I'll update the question to clarify this.